# Refit REST library - Unable to post List<Guid> in Body

Tags: c#, rest, dotnet-httpclient, guid, refit

I'm unable to post List through refit. Here's the interface declaration:

```
[Post("/api/Url/{id}")]
[Headers("Content-Type:application/json")]
Task<Model> PostMethod([Body(BodySerializationMethod.UrlEncoded)] CommandType command)
```

Here's the CommandType class

```
public class CommandType
{
    public IEnumerable<Guid> Prop { get; set; }
}
```

Even though Refit is able to make the call but the argument for Prop is null at the receiving end.

[UPDATE] I tried with [Body(BodySerializationMethod.UrlEncoded)] [Query(CollectionFormat.Multi)] too but no luck!

[FOUND SOLUTION] I've solved it using just the following by removing both Body attribute and CommandType. Instead, put the Property inside the class into the parameter directly. Just FYI.

[Query(CollectionFormat.Multi)] IEnumerable of Guid for Prop

Comment: `IEnumerable<T>` is not `List<T>`.

Comment: And how the receiving end does look? Also using `BodySerializationMethod.UrlEncoded` with `Headers("Content-Type:application/json")` looks a bit suspicious to me.

Comment: The receiving end defines it as IEnumerable<T> but I tried with List<T> without much luck.

Receiving end has the CommandType as parameter but it's received as null. Receiving end is just a POST method implementation.

I tried without Headers too but without any luck.